# Debian 11 : Can't add squashfs to /proc/filesystems

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, debian-bullseye, snap

I'm trying to fix an issue with snap I'm having :

```
root@puppeteer:~# snap install core
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-180662911: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'.
```

It seems like squashfs is installed

```
root@puppeteer:~# apt install squashfs-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
squashfs-tools is already the newest version (1:4.4-2+deb11u2).
squashfs-tools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@puppeteer:~#
```

However it is not in visible when I run the following commands

```
lsmod
cat /proc/filesystems
```

and when I run the command to load the module nothing happens at all (even after reboot).

```
modprobe squashfs
```

I can't find any information about how to load the module. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Dmesg

```
root@puppeteer:~# dmesg | grep squashfs
[   13.365857] request_module fs-squashfs succeeded, but still no fs?
```

#### Modinfo

```
root@puppeteer:~# modinfo squashfs
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.0-19-amd64/kernel/fs/squashfs/squashfs.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Phillip Lougher <phillip@squashfs.org.uk>
description:    squashfs 4.0, a compressed read-only filesystem
alias:          fs-squashfs
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           squashfs
vermagic:       5.10.0-19-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Debian Secure Boot CA
sig_key:        32:A0:28:7F:84:1A:03:6F:A3:93:C1:E0:65:C4:3A:E6:B2:42:26:43
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      2A:D8:0D:0F:F6:32:86:CE:28:94:F9:8A:2F:AB:57:5C:6D:A8:77:32:
                00:FD:A5:CB:E8:31:A9:9A:59:1F:00:06:F8:AF:98:7E:71:61:EF:E5:
                EE:AF:7A:C0:B4:6C:24:3A:4F:6E:AC:6B:7B:68:37:CA:02:26:58:B3:
                D4:FE:DA:6F:72:27:F1:1C:10:49:DC:86:3C:78:AF:FD:26:C9:D8:C7:
                27:F1:02:F7:F9:37:09:5B:48:00:E2:C2:78:B5:0D:7B:1B:D2:68:42:
                4D:14:8F:6A:6C:5F:10:EF:15:3C:CC:E9:50:C8:75:9F:50:21:11:A1:
                BE:42:58:CF:26:32:3A:58:8B:CB:B9:A0:AE:42:5B:CF:3B:BE:F7:C4:
                E2:A3:85:40:9D:16:35:53:BC:F9:B7:57:2F:B4:0E:BC:D0:B4:65:F4:
                74:C7:C2:7C:2F:C8:0A:59:DA:DC:E9:60:9E:2C:F6:C4:A0:A0:E4:05:
                54:F8:18:8A:30:6D:C1:66:80:29:F6:34:DB:DC:1B:6F:6E:BF:27:24:
                00:95:3A:9D:D1:26:42:7C:E5:6D:15:CA:72:D5:75:77:EB:8B:C3:87:
                AD:81:9D:86:02:88:0E:62:18:67:76:18:DA:E5:72:B4:70:22:A1:34:
                5F:42:B7:20:A0:4D:27:7A:CF:47:D5:F1:6C:49:6B:29
```

#### System Info

```
root@puppeteer:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.0-19-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21)
root@puppeteer:~# cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
```

Comment: `modprobe` normally doesn't output anything. Check its outcome with with `lsmod | grep squashfs` afterwards, also check `dmesg`: mine says `[2010614.161973] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher`. Finally, what `modinfo squashfs` says?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov : I checked the outcome and there was no changes to lsmod nor /proc/filesystems.  I edited question and added output of dmesg and modinfo commands.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this a bare metal or VM system, or a non-privileged child container of some sort (LXC, Docker, whatever)?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov : This is a VM....running from KVM.

Comment: Quite strange. Did you try to reboot it? It is very strange. Maybe something was corrupted.

Comment: I've shutdown/restarted many times.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were lines in my /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf file that was preventing squashfs from being installed.